# Graphics card gets very hot when my monitor is turned off or computer is locked

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, cooling

I have an EVGA gtx 970. When I turn my monitor off while in-game or when I Win+L while in-game my graphics card gets exceptionally hot.

I came back from dinner today to find it running at 100% fan speed at 76c. For comparison, it usually runs around 65c playing playing the same game on ultra. I don't know of any games I have that push the card above 70c.

So how is the card getting so incredibly hot if my monitor is off?

Comment: Did you try another driver Version? Maybe it's a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Why would your monitor be off affect the video card?  It still renders all the data, which makes the card hot.

As for the Win+L, that's up to the game on how it handles the screen being locked.  My suspicion is it doesn't handle it at all and still renders all video data.

Comment: This doesn't really answer why the card gets hot.

Comment: It gets hot because it is being used.

Comment: According to the question it doesn't get nearly as hot in active use.

Comment: If that's the case, it logically doesn't make sense.  The monitor would not affect the video card.

Comment: Right.  Hence the question.

Comment: If OP reads this, test specifically to see if you're monitor affects your card.  Try an hour with the monitor off first, then an hour after with it on.  I suspect it'll end up to about 75c at this point, even though the monitor is on.